# How to differentiate using properties of logarithms

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would I differentiate the function $\ln\dfrac{x-1}{x^3}$ by applying the properties of logarithms?

I've already differentiated using chain rule and got $-\dfrac{2x-3}{(x-1)x}$.

However, I'm not sure how to do so with the properties of logarithms.

Comment: Lookup "logarithmic derivative".

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**$$\ln\frac{x-1}{x^3} = \ln(x-1) - 3\ln(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

You should use $\ln \frac{a}{b}=\ln a - \ln b$ and then take the derivative.